# Iterating over two files containing named entity maps and calculating precision and recall

Tags: java, collections, stanford-nlp, string-matching

I have two files that I have to iterate over and calculate precision and recall for my named entity tagger. one file is the gold set and the other is the output of my system. I just want to understand how do I iterate over sentences in the two files and count the number of full and partial matches. I only want to calculate matches for organization,person and location. Pseudo code or just an idea to get me started would work very well.

File 1: Gold Set

```
Sentence 1:
{ORGANIZATION=[Fulton County Grand Jury]}
Sentence 2:
{ORGANIZATION=[City Executive Committee]}
{LOCATION=[City of Atlanta]}
Sentence 3:
{LOCATION=[Fulton]}
{PERSON=[Superior Court Judge Durwood Pye]}
{PERSON=[Mayor-nominate Ivan Allen Jr.]}
Sentence 4:
Sentence 5:
Sentence 6:
{LOCATION=[Fulton]}
Sentence 7:
{LOCATION=[Fulton County]}
Sentence 8:
Sentence 9:
{ORGANIZATION=[City Purchasing Department]}
Sentence 10:
Sentence 11:
Sentence 12:
{ORGANIZATION=[State Welfare Department]}
Sentence 13:
{LOCATION=[Fulton County]}
{ORGANIZATION=[State Welfare Department]}
{LOCATION=[Fulton County]}
```

File 2: My output

```
Sentence 1:
{ORGANIZATION=[Fulton County Grand Jury], DATE=[Friday], LOCATION=[Atlanta]}
Sentence 2:
{ORGANIZATION=[City Executive Committee], LOCATION=[Atlanta]}
Sentence 3:
{ORGANIZATION=[Fulton Superior Court Judge Durwood Pye], DATE=[September October], PERSON=[Ivan Allen Jr.]}
Sentence 4:
Sentence 5:
{LOCATION=[Georgia]}
Sentence 6:
Sentence 7:
{LOCATION=[Atlanta, Fulton County]}
Sentence 8:
Sentence 9:
{ORGANIZATION=[City Purchasing Department]}
Sentence 10:
{LOCATION=[Georgia]}
Sentence 11:
Sentence 12:
{ORGANIZATION=[State Welfare Department]}
Sentence 13:
{ORGANIZATION=[State Welfare Department], LOCATION=[Fulton County, Fulton County]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get started as below to parse the file and collect the data that is required. Below would fetch all organizations.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("path-to-file"));
    List<String> orgLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.startsWith("{ORGANIZATION")){
            orgLines.add(line);
        }
    }
```

Once you have the result of both files, you can use `retainAll` to find the complete match.

```
orgLines.retainAll(orgLines2);
```

For partial match, you need to iterate through all entries and compute based on your matching logic.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to iterate over the map values to extract organization values? See the second file. My line may not always start with Organization key..

Comment: The current exact match would just match the organizations that have same fields associated with same values - essentially the lines which are exactly matching - something like `{ORGANIZATION=[State Welfare Department]}` - but if you prefer to match just with name ignoring DATE etc, then a custom logic needs to be built.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Stanford NER, why not use the built in command to test your classifier?

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier path/to/ner-model.ser.gz -testFile gold-annotated-text.tsv
```

You will have to change your gold set to [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/ner-example/jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv) format.

Reference: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#a